# Swift app crashes when I call method from dependecy project (framework)

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, frameworks, dependencies

I'm trying to create a modular architecture in my project but I came across a very strange error.

I have a project called Application and another called Core.

In "Application" I have a storyboard that has a HomeViewController which imports Core.

In the ViewDidLoad of HomeViewController I have a custom button called btnLater of type RGButton which is declared inside of the Core project.

Xcode's Autocomplete recognizes the public methods when I type "self.btnLater." or "RGButton."

RGButton class on Core proejct:

```
public class RGButton: UIButton {

// corner radius
public func borderRadius(radius : CGFloat) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
}
...
```

HomeViewController ViewDidLoad() on Application project

```
...
self.btnLater.layer.cornerRadius = 4
self.btnLater.borderRadius(radius: 4.0)
...
```

So when I run the project... on the line

> self.btnLater.layer.cornerRadius = 4

there is no crash... But on the line

> self.btnLater.borderRadius(radius: 4.0)

it crashes with the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x1a258656e61)

I fear that some project configuration may be causing this.. but I need some light to help me figure out what the aliens are doing to my project...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if this helps but i commented out that line and it crashes again with the error:
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
trying to create a singleton on the Core project like: 

public class LoadingView {

    public static let shared: LoadingView = LoadingView()

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was... So everyone who is refactoring their project to a modular one pay attention when you use UI objects on storyboard... you have to change the Module to Core (in my case)

And make sure all Bundle.main in your project points to Bundle(identifier: "indetifier.of.framework")